# Cannot read property 'setCustomValidity' of null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script:

```
 (function (exports) {
        function valOrFunction(val, ctx, args) {
            if (typeof val == "function") {
                return val.apply(ctx, args);
            } else {
                return val;
            }
        }

        function InvalidInputHelper(input, options) {
            input.setCustomValidity(valOrFunction(options.defaultText, window, [input]));

            function changeOrInput() {
                if (input.value == "") {
                    input.setCustomValidity(valOrFunction(options.emptyText, window, [input]));
                } else {
                    input.setCustomValidity("");

                }
            }

            function invalid() {
                if (input.value == "") {
                    input.setCustomValidity(valOrFunction(options.emptyText, window, [input]));
                } else {
                    console.log("INVALID!"); input.setCustomValidity(valOrFunction(options.invalidText, window, [input]));
                }
            }

            input.addEventListener("change", changeOrInput);
            input.addEventListener("input", changeOrInput);
            input.addEventListener("invalid", invalid);
        }
        exports.InvalidInputHelper = InvalidInputHelper;
    })(window);



    InvalidInputHelper(document.getElementById("firstname"), {
        defaultText: "Please enter an firstname !",
        emptyText: "Please enter an firstname!",
        invalidText: function (input) {
            return 'The firstnames "' + input.value + '" is invalid!';
        }
    });
```

and i have this textbox:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.FirstName, new { id = "firstname", @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
```

But i get an error Cannot read property 'setCustomValidity' of null in console...what am i doing wrong? I see that is working here http://jsfiddle.net/B4hYG/437/ but for me its not...is it beacause of mvc or what?

Answer (score 2):

That script, where in your code is it located? I'm guessing it's located in the header?

In your example, if you change the second drop-down at the top left to `No wrap - in <head>`, you get the error you described and you can see it being broken [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B4hYG/566/).

This is because your elements haven't been created yet. Either you need to move your `InvalidInputHelper` function call to the bottom of the page so it runs after the elements are created, or you need to wrap it in a function to tell it to not fire until everything has run.

If you are definitely using jQuery you can wrap it with the `ready` function like so:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    InvalidInputHelper(document.getElementById("firstname"), {
        defaultText: "Please enter an firstname !",
        emptyText: "Please enter an firstname!",
        invalidText: function (input) {
            return 'The firstnames "' + input.value + '" is invalid!';
        }
    });
});
```

and [here it is working](http://jsfiddle.net/B4hYG/567/).

Or if you prefer a pure JavaScript solution you can use the vanilla alternative found [here](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready).

To reiterate though, the easiest way would be to move the call to the bottom of the page, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

i cannot "add a comment"... i reply here...

I think that the problem could be the 'document.getElementById("firstname")'.

You get it after the DOM is ready? (i don't know how MVC work)

Try to put your code:

```
InvalidInputHelper(document.getElementById("firstname"), {
    defaultText: "Please enter an firstname !",
    emptyText: "Please enter an firstname!",
    invalidText: function (input) {
        return 'The firstnames "' + input.value + '" is invalid!';
    }
});
```

in document loaded function
(example for jquery: 
    `$(function() { /* your code here */ });` )

Answer (score 0):

In react you should use `event.target.setCustomValidity`